# Unit testing in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm

I have this simple hello world app, I want to write a test for it. I am new to Nodejs so want help in getting started

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write tests using jest and supertest.

Comment: can you tell me how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

in terminal;

```
npm i supertest
npm i chai
```

then sample api test is below ;

```
describe('Hello World Api Test', () => {
    it('should return 200', (done) => {
        request(app)
            .get('/')
            .expect(200)
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(res);
                expect(res.text).to.equal('Hello world!');
                done()
            });
    });
});
```